# How to load .csv data into a photoshop

Tags: excel, text, photoshop

I have an csv document with 2 columns.  The first column shows the name of the person, the 2nd column shows the person's id. There are 900 rows of this data.  I want to create a PSD file for each row or data that is presented in my .csv file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully took advantage of creating a [dataset within Photoshop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7417a.html). This prepares your desired layer to connect with dynamic data. I then defined the source for my dataset which allows me to connect my external .csv file.   My external .csv file has one main header for labels, followed by multiple rows of data (i.e. each student's name and id).  I then made the connection and now see my single row of external data in photoshop!

**Bonus*** But if you want to batch this process for multiple rows of data after creating your first dataset, then go to file -> export -> data sets as files, and Photoshop will convert the rest of the rows from that .csv file, as individual dataset .psd files for you.

Here's another online tutorial that give visuals on what to do.
http://www.richmediacs.com/user_manuals/RMCS_PS_Training/Using%20PS%20Variables/UsingVariablesInPS_EXTERNAL.html

**The only thing that would be cooler than this, would be to load datasets into multiple layers in the same .PSD file, rather than exporting individual .PSD files.**

Answer (score 2):

not sure about reading from excel directly, but you could certainly parse out a csv format of this data and accomplish this.  As for the how, check out the 'File System Access' section of your Javascript Tools Guide pdf your extendscript toolkit install directory.  (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Utilities - CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit CS6\SDK)

Comment: thanks for the tip!  I found a way out of the box that is working for me at the moment.